Why can't my laravel database be found now even if I had already used it a few days ago?
I'm new to using the laravel framework, and I'm struggling in starting my project due to several problems I've encountered while setting up. I'm currently using Linux as my command prompt and Xampp for database management. Apparently, I have two MySQLs, one downloaded together with XAMPP and, the other, downloaded on its own. This caused me a lot of confusion. (I'm not sure if the problem is related to that.) Along with the two MySQLs, I also have 2 APACHEs, one dowloaded with XAMPP and, the other, APACHE2. So every time I try serving my laravel project and running xampp, I have to stop both the stand alones apache2 and mysql. How should I go about it? After I had fixed the problem of my XAMPP apache and mysql server not running, this problem popped up. My laravel database won't show up in my XAMPP and the project itself states that its supposed database is "unknown", though I had already served the project a few days ago with no problem. I'm thinking it might be because the database was linked to the stand alone mysql (I'm not sure), but the port of my laravel project is already editted through its env file to match XAMPP's mysql server. How do I fix this?
(https://i.sstatic.net/4jEzx1Lj.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/cbi9zjgY.png)
current status of phpmyadmin in xampp
I've tried asking generative AI but to no avail T - T I also can't ask my teachers because it's currently summer break

Yes, it'll be the two MySQL servers in conflict. Stop both, start one. Try the site. If it fails, stop both, start the other one. Try again. Remove the one you don't need.

Why you need 2 Apache webservers and 2 MySQL database servers? Both can serve more than one websites and more than one databases. I think you are confuse with Linux command promt. You can manage your databases with Windows command promt simply using mysql client.

I would say uninstall all that comes with xamp and just work with the stand alones. Then set them to start on computer boot up.


Please ask only one question per post. I understand that your questions are linked together, but the questions involve different tools and technologies and therefore you may need help from multiple different people. 2) Please think about if a question is about programming and software development or about something else. You can get help on SO for questions relating to the former, but not regarding the latter. 3) XAMPP has been using mariadb instead of mysql as database for years. No, the two are not the same and getting more and more incompatible.


In general, have only one web development environment (webserver and database server). Remove the ones that you do not need. However, you may have to move data between the various database environments before removing the extra one. And if you keep the XAMPP environment, then pls do not forget that you have mariadb and not mysql.

When I first started I, didn't really know how everything worked since it's my first time using frameworks and managing databases in general. At first, I was using the windows command prompt, but laravel won't run properly I wasn't sure why. Then I stumbled upon linux and tried again there. Somehow it worked, so I think I've accidentally duplicated my Apache and MySQL by downloading it on its own then downloading xampp. But now, I think the database is linked to the MySQL unrelated to xampp. How do I make the database appear on XAMPP instead?

Dump it from one and reimport it in the other using mysql dump. This is not a programming question as mysqldump is a sep;arate application with well documented options

Check-1
Ensure that the standalone MySQL and Apache services are stopped and disabled from starting automatically. This will prevent conflicts with XAMPP services.
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo systemctl disable mysql

sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl disable apache2

Check2
Ensure your Laravel project is configured to use the MySQL server from XAMPP. Edit the .env file in your Laravel project directory with the correct database credentials:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=your_xampp_mysql_password

Check3
Check for any running MySQL or Apache services on windows:

Press the Windows logo key and type services in the search box.
Open the Services application. Look for MySQL, MySQL57, Apache2.4,
orsimilar services.
Stop and disable these services if they arerunning to avoid conflicts with XAM



If you have really set all settings perfectly, I guess the issue is on Laravel cache.
Please clear the configuration cache using the following commands:


php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear



Otherwise, please create the necessary database for your Laravel project in phpMyAdmin (accessible via XAMPP). And then, import any existing database structure or data if needed.


you only need the config:clear command to clear ... config:cache will clear and cache
